# Python: Adding values from multiple dictionaries and merging unique keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, key-value

I have 2 dictionaries that share about 80% the same keys and the values are 2 element lists. I need to make a new dictionary out of the three that will contain all the keys, including the ones unique to each dictionary and I need the values of the same keys to be summed up.

```
    dict1 = {'Mike': [10,20], 'John': [12,34], 'Steve': [60,10]}
    dict2 = {'Mike': [15,10], 'John': [18,36]}
```

The new dictionary should look like this :

```
    dict3 = {'Mike': [25,30], 'John': [30,70], 'Steve': [60,10]}
```

Any idea how I should tackle this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: ```dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}```

Comment: This solution does not meet the need of composing each dict's values

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to do this, but here is a way that minimizes lookups, which may be helpful if the actual dicts are large:

```
keys_1 = set(dict1.keys())
keys_2 = set(dict2.keys())
all_keys = keys_1 | keys_2
for key in all_keys:
    a,b = 0,0
    if key in keys_1:
        a += dict1[key][0]
        b += dict1[key][1]
    if key in keys_2:
        a += dict2[key][0]
        b += dict2[key][1]
    dict3[key] = [a,b]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt at a somewhat functional solution for any number of dicts and any number of values to zip-sum.

Define how you want to merge entries. In this case by summing the individual components, materializing the result:

```
merge = lambda vs: list(map(sum, zip(*vs)))
```

Then define how to merge two dicts:

```
def merge_dicts(ds):
    keys = set.union(*map(set, ds))
    return {k: merge(map(lambda d: d.get(k, repeat(0)), ds))
            for k in keys}
```

Here I just go over the union of all keys, merging every dict's entry, with `repeat(0)` as default so `merge()` will just sum up zeroes for missing values.

After that you can merge your dicts like this:

```
merged = merge_dicts([dict1, dict2])
```

Comment: Would it be possible to re-use this code for Dict[str: int] or would I have to write something else? ints aren't iterable of course, but I'm wondering if the modification would be easy / simple.

Answer (score 2):

Take keys from both dicts, iterate through and populate dict3 depending on where that key in `both_key` belongs to

```
both_keys = set(list(dict1.keys()) + list(dict2.keys()))
dict3 = {}
for k in both_keys:
    if k in dict1 and k in dict2:
        dict3[k] = [sum(x) for x in zip(dict1[k], dict2[k])]
    elif k in dict1:
        dict3[k] = dict1[k]
    else:
        dict3[k] = dict2[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution use numpy :

```
import numpy as np
sum_dict = {}
for key in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys()):
    sum_dict[key] = np.add(dict1.get(key, np.zeros(2)), dict2.get(key, np.zeros(2)))
```

1. concatenate all the 2 keys
2. loop and using numpy add to sum the values, and the default value is a numpy array of zeros

And convert back to dict of list if you want

```
dict([(k,list(v)) for (k,v) in sum_dict.items()])
Out[99]:
{'John': [30, 70], 'Mike': [25, 30], 'Steve': [60.0, 10.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict1 = {'Mike': [10,20], 'John': [12,34], 'Steve': [60,10]}
dict2 = {'Mike': [15,10], 'John': [18,36]}

new_dict = {}

for x, y in dict1.items():
if x in dict2.keys():
    new_dict[x] = [a + b for a, b in zip(dict2[x], dict1[x])]
else:
    new_dict[x] = dict1[x]
print(new_dict)

#Output : {'Mike': [25, 30], 'John': [30, 70], 'Steve': [60, 10]}
```